# Working with Strings to convert to numeric value with range

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I am working with the Texas business email dataset and i want to target all companies that have 25 to 300 employees. The Schema is currently setup with the employee count as a string with values like Employee_count: "25 to 300" "1 to 100" etc and others simply a single digit like Employee_Count: "10" , "3,000" etc. Is there a way for me to first parse the string so that it converts both numbers into a numeric range, Or at least get the larger of the two numbers,  so that i can grab companies by employee count ranges?

I tried using CAST, JSON_FUNCTIONS etc but i am also fairly new to SQL so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

The end result im trying to get is to get a list of employers with 25 to 300, 301 to 1,000.

Answer (score 1):

You want to split the string at the "to" position. `Trim` all spaces and remove all `,`. Since the clean up will be used twice, we create a tempory function.

```sql
create temp function help_parse(str string) as (
safe_cast(replace(trim(str),",","") as int64)
 );

with tbl as (Select * from unnest(["25 to 300","1 to 100" ,"10","3,000","1200"]) Employee_count)

select * ,
help_parse(split(Employee_count,"to")[safe_offset(0)]) as Employee_count_low,
help_parse(split(Employee_count,"to")[safe_offset(1)]) as Employee_count_high,
from tbl
```